# Comando PHP Artisan Make:Model Não Funciona

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Estou utilizando o Composer para gerar os arquivos do meu PHP e outras coisas. Acredito que facilita muito a programação.

Por exemplo, para gerar um Controller eu faço assim:

`php artisan controller:make NomeController`

Funciona!

Mas ao digitar:

`php artisan make:model NomeModel`

Ele não funciona e apresenta esse erro:

> There are no commands defined in the "make" namespace.

Pesquisei, mas não encontrei nada. E percebi que ao digitar apenas `php artisan` - no qual mostra uma lista de comandos existentes - o do **model** realmente não existe.

O que fazer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não seria:

```
php artisan model:make NomeModel
```

Você também pode utilizar o comando:

```
php artisan
```

Para listar todos os comandos.

Caso não tenha você pode utilizar a extenção [Laravel 4 Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) que atende suas necessidades.

Adicionando algumas novas funcionalidades ao seu artisan:

```
generate:model
generate:view
generate:controller
generate:seed
generate:migration
generate:pivot
generate:resource
generate:scaffold
```

Comment: Fiz desse jeito também e não funcionou. Então, eu fiz isso de listar e não tem nada com Model.

Comment: @DiegoSouza fiz uma edição que pode te ajudar

Comment: Funcionou muito bem essa biblioteca. Ao criar o Model, ele coloca uma / antes da palavra Eloquent. É normal isso ?

Comment: sim normal sem problemas

Comment: Beleza, então. Obrigado, Mano.